# Edmx file error when opening object reference not set to an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

when I copy my project to another PC I get this error while opening the Edmx file designer mode.

```
<edmx:Edmx Version="2.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/10/edmx">
```

the first line of my Edmx file is the above code,its showing  object reference not set to an object

Comment: Probably worth checking the target .Net framework. Suggested in this [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/553b36fa-fc4a-42bc-8a44-ab582859d5bd/ef-designer-problem?forum=adodotnetentityframework) post

Comment: @Mick does not show my error there